# Mirroring C++ model class hierarchy in Model-View-Controller

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, design-patterns, factory, observer-pattern

I have a system which describes lots of devices with complex data and behavior represented by a sophisticated class hierarchy in C++. This part of the system knows nothing about the onscreen representation of these devices partially due to decoupling and partially due to possibility of many different onscreen representations possible.

Here the [MVC Design Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvc-design-pattern/) / [Model-View-Controller](http://www.laputan.org/pub/papers/POSA-MVC.pdf)  comes to play to connect view with the model. But being high level pattern, it says nothing about mirroring the class hierarchy of models in the specific language.

The reality requires to create a mirroring hierarchy of classes for every view. More than that, I should create a factory for each view which will create the respective View class object for the Model object. This is tons of dirty and similar code. Every time somebody adds a new class in Model classes hierarchy (new device), he must remember to update the Factory, since the only person who knows the relation between classes SpecficDeviceModel and SpecificDevice2DView is the developer, for the compiler they are independent classes, of course.

Some people asked to provide the example of this "dirty and similar code", so here is the overall idea of the Factory code:

```
NodeView* ViewNodesFactory(NodeModel* nodeModel) {
    std::string class_name = typeid(*nodeModel).name();
    class_name = class_name.substr(sizeof("class ") - 1);

    if (class_name == "DeviceType1") { return new DeviceType1View; } 
      else if (class_name == "DeviceType2") { return new DeviceType2View; } 
      else if (class_name == "DeviceType3") { return new DeviceType3View; }
  
    assert(0); // Type is not supported
    return new DeviceDefaultView;
}
```

Main problems of this code:

1. Easy to introduce misprints in class names.
2. Every time one adds the class to model, the factory should be updated.
3. The name of class extraction is "hacky" and error-prone, since if somebody will envelope the classes in namespace the name will change and code will broke, so it must be made even more complicated; here I showed the idea only.
4. With dozens of classes this will be classical "spaghetti code".

So here is my question. With all these recent 20/23 innovations in C++ are there any ways to simplify this task? Is there a way to represent many Model classes by many View classes without extensive "connecting" code?

**Reservations**:

For sure, I can write a sophisticated macro which will be used in place of declaration of Views which will fulfill Factory database.

Of course, I can write python script to update the Factory based on my naming convention.

But as for me these are complex "hacky" workarounds. Are there any straightforward ways to solve this in C++? As far as I know we still have no reflection in C++ to do this.

Comment: you should include an example of "tons of dirty and similar code" ?

Comment: Should I? It is very obvious code which will make the question too long. The code is to add the relation between view class and model class to the Factory, initialize pointer to model in view class, gather data from model class. All this boring and dirty code will make the question long and non-informative.

Comment: no its not obvious. Of course you can develop a mvc framework that takes away the boilerplate from the user. This was possible in C++98. You assume someone knows how to do this without the boilerplate but at the same time assume they know how your boilerplate looks.

Comment: You could have each view have a container of pointers to models and vice versa.  This allows you to not hard code relationships, but to also have them created on the fly.

Comment: in other words, nothing is really obvious and I dare to say that if your process of solving this leads to lots of boilerplate then its your process fault. You need to tell us about it so we can show you where you took the wrong path.

Comment: For example "...since the only person who knows the relation between classes SpecficDeviceModel and SpecificDevice2DView is the developer, for the compiler they are independent classes, of course." a relation between pairs of classes can be established in a way it is *known* to the compiler without much boilerplate

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, this is exactly one of my questions, how to do this on fly? Can you pinpoint some solution or article? With "pointers to models" do you mean pointers to "device objects" in my terms? Not sure about "and vice versa", since "server" (model) shouldn't have information about views. Can you pinpoints to examples where this implemented?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, point taken. Let me extract some representative part of this really long code. BTW, what way you suggest to "establish a relation between two classes known to the compiler without much boilerplate" so that it could be used in Factory which is called when I get another model object from enumerator? I get object of SpecficDeviceModel class. How can I simply create an instance of SpecificDevice2DView without two workarounds above? Do you suggest to use RTTI and typeid?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, before I extract the code, would it work without the code if I reword the question into "which is the best way to reflect/mirror and connect two hierarchies of classes - in model and in view? Let's don't focus on the code, let's focus on the best solution for this. The SpecificDevice2DView  has the pointer to the SpecficDeviceModel object and RTTI/typeid is used to create the respective View object for Model object. Is this the best solution or there is a better approach with 20/23 C++?

Comment: consider that if you feel that its too much to fit in one question then perhaps it is. You can split it up in smaller questions. Also, often asking about one detail aspect helps with the rest too. For the start you could eg focus on: "I have a class SpecificDeviceModel and a class SpecificDevice2DView, and I have this code [....] that is necessary to glue this two together, in the future I want to add [...], how I can I avoid to repeat this code?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252007/discussion-between-damir-tenishev-and-463035818-is-not-a-number).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, as you requested I added the code for the factory.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, views have a different responsibility than the models and - depending on the application - one view class could be used for two different models (e.g. a slider or a combobox). Therefore it doesn't usually make sense to mirror the class hierarchy of the models for the views.

You can still reduce the boilerplate:

One fairly simple improvement would be to have a virtual factory method `create_view` in the base class `NodeModel` of the model. Then the factory method can delegate to the overriden method. As a consequence, you never have to touch the factory method when you introduce a new pair of concrete models/views.

Here is a rough example:

```cpp
#include <typeindex> 
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// base class for your views
struct NodeView
{
    // just for demonstration purposes:
    virtual void say_hello() const = 0;
};

// abstract base class for your models
struct NodeModel
{
    virtual std::shared_ptr<NodeView> create_view() const = 0;
};


// the factory function delegates to NodeModel::create_view
std::shared_ptr<NodeView> ViewNodesFactory(NodeModel const& nodeModel) {
    return nodeModel.create_view();
}

// A concrete model/view implementation follows. 

struct ConcreteView : public NodeView
{
    void say_hello() const override 
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from ConcreteView\n";
    }
};

struct ConcreteModel : public NodeModel
{
    std::shared_ptr<NodeView> create_view() const override
    {
        return std::make_shared<ConcreteView>();
    }
};

int main()
{
  
    ConcreteModel x;

    auto view = ViewNodesFactory(x);
    view->say_hello();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oK77fMzhf

As a downside, the model is not independent of the view. If you want the model to be completely agnostic of the view and keep the possibility to use different views for the same model, you would have to be able to register the type of view to be created given a model instance at runtime. To be able to do this, you could store an `unordered_map` having `std::type_index` as a key and (type erased) factory methods as a value.

Here is an example, where the factory is a singleton functor.

```cpp
#include <typeindex> 
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// base class for your views
struct NodeView
{
    // just for demonstration purposes:
    virtual void say_hello() const = 0;
};

// base class for your models (must be polymorphic for typeid!)
struct NodeModel
{
    virtual ~NodeModel(){}
};


// the factory function delegates to NodeModel::create_view
class ViewFactory
{
public:

    std::shared_ptr<NodeView> create(NodeModel const& nodeModel) {

        auto idx = std::type_index(typeid(nodeModel));

        if ( factories.contains(idx)) {
            return factories.at(idx)();
        }

        throw std::out_of_range("Not registered");
    }

    static ViewFactory& get_instance() 
    {
        static ViewFactory factory;
        return factory;
    }

    template <typename Model, typename F>
    void register_factory(F&& f)
    {
        factories.insert(
            {
                typeid(Model), 
                Factory(std::forward<F>(f))
            }
        );
    }

    ViewFactory(ViewFactory const&) = delete;
    ViewFactory(ViewFactory&&) = delete;
private:
    ViewFactory() = default;

    using Factory = std::function<std::shared_ptr<NodeView>()>;
    using Map = std::unordered_map<std::type_index, Factory>;
    Map factories;
};

// A concrete model/view implementation follows. 

struct ConcreteView : public NodeView
{
    void say_hello() const override 
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from ConcreteView\n";
    }

    // This is optional: You could also register a lambda or any other
    // factory as long as the signature matches
    static std::shared_ptr<NodeView> create()
    {
        return std::make_shared<ConcreteView>();
    }
};

struct ConcreteModel : public NodeModel
{};

int main()
{
  
    ConcreteModel x;

    ViewFactory::get_instance().register_factory<ConcreteModel>(
        &ConcreteView::create
    );

    auto view = ViewFactory::get_instance().create(x);
    view->say_hello();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Wcs4hxE3e

Note, that there is no C++20/C++23 magic involved. The second example only uses C++20 for convenience, because of the use of `unordered_map::contains` method. I don't think that concepts/auto parameters are of much use for your usage scenario: You could get rid of some of the overhead involved with the type-erased factory methods and the dynamic dispatch, but I assume you still need to be able to store models and views in a heterogeneous container, so you still need polymorphism anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the examples. Before I provide my comments and answers one small question on your code? Why do you need this (virtual std::type_index get_type_index() const = 0;) method? Actually you call it in ViewFactory::create where its implementation could be substituted, since it will work on NodeModel& correctly because RTTI has all the necessary information. So, you will be able not change the NodeModel class at all. My code above relies on this and works well. Do you have special reasons for this method? Want to turn off RTTI or other reasons?

Comment: Good catch! I forgot that typeid handles polymoprhic classes in this way. For this to work, `NodeModel` has to be polymorphic (at least one virtual method) though. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the examples and answers. Actually, this is the key point of my question, I wanted to avoid this tons of code, especially in the second "insulated" case (of course, the first doesn't work for me, I might have many different views, so need the decoupling). I thought they improved C++ a bit to simplify such patterns. Anyway, the key answer from you came in the chat where you pointed that view hierarchy shouldn't reflect the model hierarchy. If you like to put this (with some explanation) at the beginning of your answer, I would like to mark it "Accepted" to make useful for others.